# scheduleLocalNotification is not working in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uilocalnotification, alarm

I'm a newbie in iOS technology.I'm trying to build an alarm app with swift 2.0 by using UILocalNotification. When I click button, I get the time and date from the UIPickerView. I want to display notification and play sound also.
But both sound and notification are not working. Please help me!

```
@IBOutlet weak var myPickerView: UIDatePicker!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myPickerView.date = NSDate()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func setAlarmClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    let dateFormater : NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormater.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    dateFormater.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
    dateFormater.dateStyle = .ShortStyle

    let dateTimeString : NSString = dateFormater.stringFromDate(myPickerView.date)
    print("date is \(dateTimeString)")

    self.sheduleLocalNotificationWithDate(myPickerView.date)
}

@IBAction func cancelAlarmClicked(sender: UIButton) {

}

func sheduleLocalNotificationWithDate(fireDate : NSDate){
    let localNotification : UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.fireDate = fireDate
    localNotification.alertBody = "Alert !!!!"
    localNotification.soundName = "minion.mp3"

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to register for local notifications. Add this to your view controller:

```
override func viewDidAppear() {

    super.viewDidAppear()
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

}
```

An alert will come up when your view appears for the first time, hit "OK" and your notifications should work. Remember that the user can always disable notifications.

Comment: @lnuyasha If you mean the notification will still fire, then yes.

Comment: It is working find if the app is running in background or terminated. But if I still run it in foreground, it doesn't work. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Inuyasha Yes, notifications do not appear when your app is in the foreground. It's unfortunate, but you have to implement a custom way of doing it. There is an app delegate method called `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` in which you can perform any foreground code. However, that delegate method is **not** called when your notification fires in the background.